# DRF PrimaryKeyRelatedField, AttributeError: 'QuerySet object has no attribute parameter'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get a REST-backend up and running, my first in Python. 
An incident can have many UnderWays but an UnderWay may only have one Incident(ManyToOne).

I'm now trying to get the serializer for the UnderWay model to work, it should do both POST and GET requests with the following parameters['incident', 'phonenumber', 'time'].

It feels as if I've tried everything but all I get is an AttributeError saying 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'incident'.

**models.py:**

```
class Incident(models.Model):
active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
message = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_created=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class UnderWay(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    incident = models.ForeignKey(Incident, null=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_created=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class LastIncidentApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
"""This class defines the create behavior of our rest api."""
queryset = [Incident.objects.order_by('created_at')[0]]
serializer_class = IncidentSerializer

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    """Save the post data when creating a new incident."""
    serializer.save()


class UnderWayApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """This class defines the create behavior of our rest api."""
    # active = Incident.objects.latest('created_at').pk
    queryset = [UnderWay.objects.all()]
    serializer_class = UnderWaySerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Save the post data when creating a new incident."""
        serializer.save()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class IncidentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
    model = Incident
    fields = ('id', 'active', 'message',
               'time',
              'created_at', 'updated_at')
    read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')


class UnderWaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    incident = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Incident.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True))

    class Meta:
        model = UnderWay
        fields = ('incident', 'telephone', 'time', 'created_at')
        read_only_field = 'created_at'
```

I do however get the GET-requests to work if I make the incident field in the serializer a ReadOnlyField. But that's not really helping me a lot.

Thankful for any help :)

Comment: there's sth bad in your views : your queryset are not Django query sets but lists. It does not mean that it is the problem but, that's an issue

Comment: Hi, I think maybe you misunderstand querysets. Querysets are objects that are iterable, so you don't need to put them into lists. When you write `[Underway.objects.all()]` you are actually creating a list with one element, which is a queryset. There are some good tutorials about querysets, for example:  https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a cleaner code, you should define a IncidentApiView with

```
queryset=Incident.objects.all()
```

and no perform_create (useless IMO, as what you're doing comes from the Create part of ListCreateAPIView)

LastIncidentView could be a ListAPIView where you override perform_read to get only the last one (there's no reason to POST a "Last Incident", you only want to POST an incident, which at a time will be the current last)

For UnderWayApiView, queryset should be

```
UnderWay.objects.all()
```

For UnderWaySerializer,

```
incident = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Incident.objects.all())
```

should be better

I'm not saying that it will fix your problem, but it should be more respectful of what DRF expects

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your serializer,

```
incident = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Incident.objects.all())
```

And in your view,

```
queryset = UnderWay.objects.all()
```